# Delphi .cfg file Paths

Tags: delphi, path, configuration-files, shortcut

Hi the path list in my project CFG file is too long, how can i define a path shortcut like $(BDS)
Thank you

Comment: `$(ENV)` is makefile-style macro substitute, where `ENV` is environment variable name. List all IDE-defined vars by launching `cmd` from tools menu and then using `set` command

Answer (score 9, accepted):

'Options' dialog -> 'Environment Options' -> 'Environment Variables'. This page has a section 'User overrides'. That's where you define your shortcut. You can use a fully qualified path or the already defined '$(BDS)' for variable value. Example:

```
Variable  Value
CGR       $(BDS)\..\..
THR       S:\Dev\Codegear\3rd
```

Later in the library paths use them like `$(THR)\JVCL\...`.